# VBA Creating a clocking sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I would like to create a register of the clocks that I make. When I come at work I click on a button and it adds the hour in the right cell so it can count my time. But I would like to automate that. My issue is VBA... Can some one help me with that please?
Here is what I need.

By selecting the button on the interface tab, it sends the actual time value to the other tab. It looks first which line is the today's line and which column it can paste the value (as close to the left as possible) I would like to add a few clocks not only one.

In my second tab, I've used the column C to find the today's date and put a "x". Also for aesthetic. I'm trying to do one step after the other but I don't know the formulas and properties that I can use...

```
Sub Clock()

Dim foundDate As Range
Set foundDate = Range("C:C").Find("x")

End Sub
```

Please see the pictures bellow.

Thank you for your help.

[image: Calendar, cell L211]

[image: Interface button]

---

Here is the code inspirated by your comments (I tried to understand and modify in accordance to what I needed):

```
Sub mark_today()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Calendrier")

Dim todayCel As Range
On Error Resume Next ' if there's nothing found
Set todayCel = ws.Range("E:E").Find(what:=Date)
On Error GoTo 0

If todayCel Is Nothing Then
    ' Do something if today's date can't be found
ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "I")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "I").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "I").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "J")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "J").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "J").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "L")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "L").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "L").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "M")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "M").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "M").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "O")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "O").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "O").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "P")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "P").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "P").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "R")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "R").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "R").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "S")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "S").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "S").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "U")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "U").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "U").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "V")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "V").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "V").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "X")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "X").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "X").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "Y")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "Y").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "Y").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "AA")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "AA").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "AA").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "AB")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "AB").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "AB").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "AD")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "AD").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "AD").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "AE")) = True Then
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "AE").Value = Now
    ws.Cells(todayCel.Row, "AE").NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: L'ánglais silvousplait :) Bonjour

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that it was english here, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sub will look for today's date in Column E of the "Calendrier" worksheet, and if found, put an "X" in column L of that row.

```
Sub mark_today()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Calendrier")

Dim todayCel As Range
On Error Resume Next ' if there's nothing found
Set todayCel = ws.Range("E:E").Find(what:=Date)
On Error GoTo 0

If todayCel Is Nothing Then
    ' Do something if today's date can't be found
Else
    Cells(todayCel.Row, "L").Value = "X"
End If
End Sub
```

Just assign that macro to your Button.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. It helped me a lot. I tried to understand the code and modify it to work with what I need.

Answer (score 0):

**This method will help you to automate, *Clock/Attendance Sheet*:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in Cell `L2`:

`=IF(ISBLANK($M2),"","X")`

- Enter this Formula in Cell `O2`:

  `=IF(OR(ISBLANK($M2),ISBLANK($N2)),"",INT($N2-$M2)&" days "&TEXT($N2-$M2,"h"" hrs ""m"" mins """))`
- *Fill both Formula down.*

---

- **Copy** & **Paste** this VBA code as standard module.

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M2:N5")) Is Nothing Then
      Cancel = True
      Target.Formula = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss AM/PM")
  End If
  End Sub
  ```

**N.B.**

- Apply `mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss AM/PM` format in Range `M2:N5`.
- **Double Click** cell in Range `M2:N5` beside your/employee's name to input, **In-Time** as well as **Out Time**.
- In above VBA code, Range `Range("M2:N5")` and `Date Time` Format are editable.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to help you @R.Guerreiro,,, keep asking,,☺